# collection_select with multipe true sends params with an empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The select_options tag in my application generates a param list which always contains an empty string at the beginning.
This leads to an error when the params are used to fetch data from database.

the form part is like this:

```
<%= f.label :text %><br>
<%= f.text_area :text, cols: 80, rows: 15, class: 'form-control' %>


<%= f.label 'Category:' %>

<%= f.collection_select(:categories, Category.all, :id, :cat_name, {:selected => Category.first.id}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

the output (html) is like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="article[categories][]" id="article_categories">
  <input name="article[categories][]" value="" type="hidden">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">default</option>
  <option value="2">politics</option>
</select>
```

That looks perfect to me. But when submitted (with the two options selected) the parameters look like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kvYo6rb+lswUuJMHpbb+hH3YFjHU25/ESN7vvLLdlVn1TOSgzyiMsXkrJbiWIhuuO4UvNLQ3jU7uTw0zneVTUA==", 
"article"=>{"title"=>"test category", "text"=>"Na mal sehen...\r\nIses drin?", 
"categories"=>["", "1", "2"], "published"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Save changes", "id"=>"76"}
```

The categories part contains: categories"=>["", "1", "2"]
The first is an empty string and i cant figure out how to get rid of it.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails generates a hidden field which has the same name as the select field, so that if no options are selected a value is still submitted. You can prevent Rails from adding the hidden field by specifying `include_hidden: false` for the collection_select.

Here is an excerpt from the explanation ([link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)):

> To prevent this the helper generates an auxiliary hidden field before
>   every multiple select. The hidden field has the same name as multiple
>   select and blank value.
>
> Note: The client either sends only the hidden field (representing the
>   deselected multiple select box), or both fields. This means that the
>   resulting array always contains a blank string.
>
> In case if you don’t want the helper to generate this hidden field you
>   can specify include_hidden: false option.

Answer (score 0):

Wizard's solution have some negative effects: we can not empty the fields once we set.
I found that we can config the strong parameter like following to fix the problem:

```
params.require(:article).permit(categories: []);
```

I found that `permit(:categories)` **not work** but `permit(categories: [])` **works**.

Comment: I've attempted this, but it still gives me an empty string.